# How to achieve ReplayGain in NAudio?

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

I made an audio player using NAudio. It works fine but the volume fluctuate low and high depending upon the mp3 file. How to achieve replaygain using NAudio? 
Suppose if i have calculated the replaygain and added to the metadata by any other means, how to dynamically adjust volume at run time? Is there any built in function for this? If not how to do it?

**Edit**

---

I'm using volume slider to adjust volume of each song according to the dB value of track gain like below

```
//-10.56 is track gain info in dB of a song. Track peak is 1.274087
var result = Math.Exp((-10.56) * (2.302585092994046 / 20.0));
decibel = (float)result;
volumeSlider1.Volume = decibel;
setVolumeDelegate(volumeSlider1.Volume);
```

is this the correct method? what is the purpose of Track peak?

Answer (score 3):

ReplayGain has a spec: [Here](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=ReplayGain_1.0_specification)

You'll specifically want to read the Player Requirements section.  In NAudio, you can use a VolumeSampleProvider to apply the gain.  Just set its Volume to whatever you calculate from the ReplayGain whenever loading a new file.

Comment: @ioctLR if I get 5.3 track gain, how much volume should I increase? Could you please let me know what formula to use?